# iPhone - how do I refresh/redraw a button that has changed state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, redraw

I am currently using NSNotifications to send a message from my app delegate to a UIView in my iPhone application.

The notification gets received by the UIView and I then use a selector to change the state of a button on the UIView.

Here is the function that is passed to the selector:

```
-(void)changeButtonState
{
    NSLog(@"Change button state received");
    [testButton setEnabled:NO];
    [testButton setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This gets called however the button state never gets visually changed, it functionally becomes disabled but looks like its still enabled on the screen.

So it looks like setNeedsDisplay either doesn't work here or is incorrect coding on my part?

Can anyone tell me how I should properly redraw the button or view when I change the state?

Comment: I'm sure you'll have thought of this, but because you don't mention it in your question just to be sure: are you setting a new image/title/etc for `UIControlStateDisabled` on your button, either in IB or code? Normally calling `setEnabled` would automatically cause the button to be redrawn for its new state, unless you haven't set a different state or reimplemented it in a subclass.

Comment: Are you sure `testButton` is connected and not `nil`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think setNeedsDisplay will only work when called on the main thread. So try calling `performSelectorOnMainThread` maybe?

Comment: @Mike C, that worked, if you want to add it as an answer please feel to do so and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since UI refreshing is usually done on the main thread, `setNeedsDisplay` will only get called on the main thread. Therefore, you need to make sure you are calling it on the main thread by using `performSelectorOnMainThread`.